# Pass dynamic parameters to React Query in button click

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Is the only way to handle this to store the `date` from `handleOnClick` into a `useState` variable, and then have it refetch in the `useEffect`?  Is there any way I can just call React Query in `handleOnClick`?

```
const { data, refetch } = useQuery(
  [day],
  () => getTimes(day),  // i cannot instantiate day here as it needs to be passed in by handleOnClick parameter
  {
    enabled: false,
  }
);

export const getTimes = async (day: string) => {
  const response = await fetch(`/api/calendar?byDay=true&day=${day}`);
  return await response.json();
};

const handleOnClick = async (date: string) => {
  // date param is getting returned here by a 3rd party component
  
  const times = await getTimes(date);  // what i normally would do
  // refetch;                          // what i would like to do but can't
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass `date` to `refetch`? If so, you can't. Also, note that using `refetch` is not the idiomatic way of doing things in react query.

Comment: @ivanatias hi yes i am.  i'm having trouble figuring this out.. for some reason on the tutorials online aren't really covering how i can call a query with a dynamic parameter like that in a function so appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/disabling-queries):

> Permanently disabling a query opts out of many great features that TanStack Query has to offer (like background refetches), and it's also not the idiomatic way. It takes you from the declarative approach (defining dependencies when your query should run) into an imperative mode (fetch whenever I click here). It is also not possible to pass parameters to refetch. Oftentimes, all you want is a lazy query that defers the initial fetch.

You can define a state for the selected day and set it on the `handleOnClick` function, then include that state in your `queryKey` array so the query will be triggered whenever that value changes. Also, you can set the `enabled` option based on that state's value:

```
const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState<string | null>(null)

const { data } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['dates', selectedDay],
  queryFn: () => getTimes(selectedDay),
  enabled: Boolean(selectedDay)
})
```

Then on the `handleOnClick` function:

```
const handleOnClick = (date: string) => {
  setSelectedDay(date)
}
```

Comment: thank you for this.  will check it out when I'm back home and give credit if it works!